# Multi lingual full text search with Sphinx

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, sphinx

I have been able to setup sphinx for full text search for english language. However what I have is multi-lingual text (hindi-english) mixed on which I need to create index.

I couldn't find much about how to implement that in sphinx.

Or do I need to switch to some other database.

Comment: Have you tried Manticore Search (fork of Sphinx)? https://pastebin.com/Ff611MxY

Answer (score 0):

In general you 'just' need to setup `charset_table` to include all word characters you want to search
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-charset-table.html

Alas the default setup only really has good defined charset tables for English and Russian - left to implement charset_table rules for other languages yourself.

The wiki
http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=charset_tables
does have a Devanagari list might be usable?

Manticore Search (mentioned in the comment) does have more elaborate charset_tables by default. Its default 'non_cjk' should support Hindi. Can either just use it in Manticore , or could (with a bit of effort) backport it and use it in Sphinx.
https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch/tree/master/src/charsets